# LWJGL texture artifacts

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, artifacts

I have a problem with textures in LWJGL:

[image]
<sub>(source: [socplay.pl](http://uploads.socplay.pl/images/13/89/67215.png))</sub>

It looks like some sort of texture artifact. What is this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could be Z-fighting.

Comment: did you locate the problem in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted much detail, but this looks like [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) to me.

Z-fighting is a phenomenon that occurs if you render two (or more) polygons that almost exactly overlap, but with different textures, colours or lighting. Because the two polygons are in almost exactly the same place, small floating-point errors can cause the "which polygon is in front" test to be unpredictable on a pixel-by-pixel basis.

Comment: If I disable "GL_DEPTH_TEST" are not artifac, but are "invisible" objects. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: @MisterVento3 Stop rendering things twice with different lighting?